# Prevent users from accessing URLs using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an htaccess code that prevents the user from accessing a song file via URL but the issue I'm having here is that when I click the download button, it won't download the song. please is there any way I can adjust it in order to download the song except the URL?

Here is the code:

```
RewriteRule \.(|mp3|)$ - [F,L]
```

what I'm expecting is only to avoid being downloaded from the URL

Comment: What's the difference between the URL a user would use to "access the song" and the URL they would use to "download the song"?

Comment: What I meant is the URL for the address bar and the URL for the download button, so I want users to have only access from the download button not from the address bar. The reason is that I found out some users normally copy the address link for a song and paste it on the address bar instead of using the download button.

Comment: "What I meant is the URL for the address bar and the URL for the download button" - so, what's the difference between these requests? Unless you are specifically making a different type of request (different URL, different request header, etc.) then there is no difference between "downloading" and entering the URL into the address bar... they both result in the file being "downloaded". Although one potentially sets the `Referer` and the other does not - but this is unreliable.

Comment: "The reason is that I found out some users normally copy the address link for a song and paste it on the address bar instead of using the download button." - What is the problem with that?

Comment: okay but is it possible to use header request with js

Comment: "The reason is that I found out some users normally copy the address link for a song and paste it on the address bar instead of using the download button. - What is the problem with that?" let me be specific, actually I'm developing a music site where the user can log in, subscribe to play, and download songs, so I want to stop users been able to track the song in another way. e.g being able to copy the song address link and paste it on the address bar of a browser and from there they would gain access to my song file.

Comment: Hello, MrWhite. Are you still with me?

Comment: "let me be specific" - Yes, please be specific and update your question with the additional information. "the user can log in" - "can" or "must" login? Can unauthenticated users play/download songs? This is potentially very different to what you are asking in your question. _Aside:_ Why are you using _alternation_ in the regex `\.(|mp3|)$`?